# Example of Time Series Prediction using Neural Networks in R

Tags: r, neural-network, time-series

Anyone's got a quick short educational example how to use Neural Networks (**nnet in R**) for the purpose of prediction?
Here is an example, **in R**,  of a time series

```
T = seq(0,20,length=200)
Y = 1 + 3*cos(4*T+2) +.2*T^2 + rnorm(200)
plot(T,Y,type="l")
```

Many thanks

David

Comment: Isn't `nnet` limited to qualitative variables, i.e., classification problems?
You may have more luck with the `neuralnet` or `AMORE` packages.
Also note that since your function is unbounded, sigmoid transfer functions (not the only choice, but often the default) are unlikely to give a useable result. For time series, to account for autoregression, people typically use [recurrent networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network), which are much more complicated...

Comment: This isn't a programming question and is better suited to http://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks guys, at least you give me some ideas. I have been told Neural Networks can be used to predict "jumpy-seasonal" time series. It's possible to apply a transformation that makes the time series bounded. I'll have a look at stats.stackexchage as well :)

Answer (score 17):

I think  you can use the `caret` package and specially the `train` function

> ```
> This function sets up a grid of tuning parameters for a number 
>       of classification and regression routines.
> ```

```
require(quantmod) 
require(nnet)
require(caret)
T = seq(0,20,length=200)
y = 1 + 3*cos(4*T+2) +.2*T^2 + rnorm(200)
dat <- data.frame( y, x1=Lag(y,1), x2=Lag(y,2))
names(dat) <- c('y','x1','x2')
dat <- dat[c(3:200),] #delete first 2 observations
#Fit model
model <- train(y ~ x1+x2 , 
               dat, 
               method='nnet', 
               linout=TRUE, 
               trace = FALSE)
ps <- predict(model, dat)

#Examine results

plot(T,Y,type="l",col = 2)
lines(T[-c(1:2)],ps, col=3)
legend(5, 70, c("y", "pred"), cex=1.5, fill=2:3)
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful ! Thanks agstudy. This is irrelevant but, it's a pain to upload all these packages (and their addons), can I ask you if there is a quick way to do it?

Comment: If you were to predict the value for timne =30, how would you do it? How come you chose x1=Lag(y,1), x2=Lag(y,2), I mean is it specific to this time series?

Comment: Why painful? only 2 packages! `caret` and `nnet`! `quantomod` for the lag!

Comment: I guess because carnet depends on : lattice, reshape2, stats, plyr, cluster, foreach. These seem to need : iterators, reshape2, zoo ...etc

Comment: @DavidKhireche, try `install.packages("caret", dependencies=TRUE)`

Comment: I don't know what the problem is but I keep getting : In open.connection(con, "r") :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '407 Proxy Authentication Required' Even though I have picked up the --internet2 option:  "C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.2 Bis\bin\i386\Rgui.exe" --internet2 !

Comment: Regarding package dependencies, you definitely consider RStudio. It makes it real simple in ensuring that the needed dependencies are loaded

Comment: @agstudy, can `nnet` do `neuralnet`'s `model <- neuralnet(T1+T2+T3~covar1+covar2+...+covarN, other options)`? (where `T1`, `T2` and `T3` are time indicators so the output would be three columns per row corresponding to these time point)

Comment: @agstudy Thank you for excellent example. Is it possible to predict/forecast future values, say for 201, 201, 203 and so on

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by @agstudy is useful, but in-sample fits are not a reliable guide to out-of-sample forecasting accuracy. The gold standard in forecasting accuracy measurement is to use a holdout sample. Remove the last 5 or 10 or 20 observations (depending to the length of the time series) from the training sample, fit your models to the rest of the data, use the fitted models to forecast the holdout sample and simply compare accuracies on the holdout, using Mean Absolute Deviations (MAD) or weighted Mean Absolute Percentage Errors (wMAPEs).
So to do this you can change the code above in this way:

```
require(quantmod) 
require(nnet)
require(caret)
t = seq(0,20,length=200)
y = 1 + 3*cos(4*t+2) +.2*t^2 + rnorm(200)
dat <- data.frame( y, x1=Lag(y,1), x2=Lag(y,2))
names(dat) <- c('y','x1','x2')
train_set <- dat[c(3:185),]
test_set <- dat[c(186:200),]
#Fit model
model <- train(y ~ x1+x2 , 
               train_set, 
               method='nnet', 
               linout=TRUE, 
               trace = FALSE)
ps <- predict(model, test_set)

#Examine results

plot(T,Y,type="l",col = 2)
lines(T[c(186:200)],ps, col=3)
legend(5, 70, c("y", "pred"), cex=1.5, fill=2:3)
```

This last two lines output the wMAPE of the forecasts from the model

```
sum(abs(ps-test_set["y"]))/sum(test_set)
```